# PHPmailer won't use SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer 6.2 (shared webhosting so I grabbed the latest version of the code from Github and uploaded it to my FTP. When I want to send mail without SMTP, there are no problems sending mail. When I do use SMTP (and I do need to), however, nothing happens. It kind of looks like the page won't load at all. I don't get errors or notices, so I'm at a loss what I'm doing wrong here. Using an SMTP test tool, I see that my credentials and the connection details are OK. Here's my code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require __DIR__.'/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    
try {
    $mail->setFrom("xxx", "Test");
    $mail->addAddress('xxx', 'Test');
    $mail->Subject = 'Bericht via de website';
    $mail->Body = "hier een testbericht"; 

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;     
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Username = 'xxx';
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';
    $mail->Port = 587;


    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
die("done");
?>
```

Edit: after 20 minutes of loading, the following response is generated:

````
2020-11-28 19:40:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO <my/e-mail rcpt domain>
2020-11-28 19:45:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:45:07 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2020-11-28 19:45:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO <my/e-mail rcpt domain>
2020-11-28 19:50:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:50:07 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed:
2020-11-28 19:50:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2020-11-28 19:55:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:55:07 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-11-28 19:55:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-11-28 20:00:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 20:00:07 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.```
````

Comment: `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant
`
Add this to your code so you can see the errors. Try you launch the script from terminal.

Comment: I'm not getting debug info now as the page itself doesn't seem to be loading at all. How do you mean, terminal?

Comment: You can try modifying like this for testing
$mail->Body = "<b>hier een testbericht</b>"; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "hier een testbericht"; //Text Body

Comment: Thanks, however adding HTML body doesn't change the page not being loaded.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: After 20 minutes of loading, I finally get a result (1/2):
2020-11-28 19:40:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:40:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO xxx
2020-11-28 19:45:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:45:07 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2020-11-28 19:45:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO xxx
2020-11-28 19:50:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:50:07 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed:
2020-11-28 19:50:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS

Comment: (2/2)
2020-11-28 19:55:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 19:55:07 SMTP ERROR: STARTTLS command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2020-11-28 19:55:07 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2020-11-28 20:00:07 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2020-11-28 20:00:07 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Where 'xxx' is my domain as well as the domain of the e-mail recipient

Comment: Ro, which logs am I to check out? I don't have access to SMTP logs on Google's side do I?

Comment: This looks like a regular firewall block. You say that an SMTP test works, but I’m guessing that’s not from the same location. Do the tests in the troubleshooting guide to confirm, and check your hosting provider’s policy on outbound SMTP.

Comment: The reason it takes a long time to time out is because that’s what the SMTP spec says it should do. SMTP is not well suited to sending during page loads.